# Does the rowMappper in spring work for assigning a row to another object?

Tags: spring

I have a DAO in my spring project which gets two variables from other tables. I want to fetch a row by ID in this DAO and I want to have those two variables as objects in return. I wrote the DAO class and my rowMapper class as below. But I can not get the author and publisher objects. I am getting nullPointerException. How should I get those objects in my book object(my author and publisher DAO work fine.)?

```
Feb 21, 2015 3:20:33 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3d82c5f3: startup date [Sat Feb 21 15:20:33 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 21, 2015 3:20:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Feb 21, 2015 3:20:33 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hojat.LibSpringProject.DAO.AuthorDAO.getAuthorById(AuthorDAO.java:17)
    at com.hojat.LibSpringProject.DAO.BookDAO$BookMapper.mapRow(BookDAO.java:185)
    at com.hojat.LibSpringProject.DAO.BookDAO$BookMapper.mapRow(BookDAO.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:805)
    at com.hojat.LibSpringProject.DAO.BookDAO.getBookById(BookDAO.java:22)
    at com.hojat.LibSpringProject.service.TestService.main(TestService.java:26)


public class BookDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {
public Book getBookById(int bookId) throws SQLException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    String sql = "select * from library.tbl_book where bookId = ?";
    return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql,new Object[] { bookId }, new BookMapper());
}


private static final class BookMapper implements RowMapper<Book> {

    @Override
    public Book mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
        Book book = new Book();
        Author author = new Author();
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
        AuthorDAO authorDAO = new AuthorDAO();
        PublisherDAO publisherDAO = new PublisherDAO();

        try {
            book.setBookId(rs.getInt("bookId"));
            book.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            author = authorDAO.getAuthorById(rs.getInt("authId"));
            book.setAuthor(author);
            publisher = publisherDAO.getPublisherById(rs.getInt("pubId"));
            book.setPublisher(publisher);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return book;
    }

public class AuthorDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {

public Author getAuthorById(int authorId) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_author where authorId = ?";
    return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql,
            new Object[] { authorId }, new AuthorMapper());

public class PublisherDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {

public Publisher getPublisherById(int publisherId)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String sql = "select * from library.tbl_publisher where publisherId = ?";
    return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql,
            new Object[] { publisherId }, new PublisherMapper());
```

Comment: You are creating AuthorDAO and PublisherDAO by new operator.I can't see place when you are setting DataSources or other connections to database. Can you paste default constructors for those DAOs?

Comment: I added my AuthorDAO and PublisherDAO classes to my original questions. I am new in Spring maybe  I went totally wrong.

Comment: When you ask about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception, and tell which line it refers to.

Comment: The Exception is already added to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

AuthorDAO and PublisherDAO  are based on JdbcDaoSupport, so they should be created by Spring, and DataSource will be injcected.
Try to inject those implementations instead creating it using new operator.

```
public class BookDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    AuthorDAO authorDAO;

    @Autowired
    PublisherDAO publisherDAO;

    public Book getBookById(int bookId) throws SQLException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
        String sql = "select * from library.tbl_book where bookId = ?";
    return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql,new Object[] { bookId }, new BookMapper());
}


private static final class BookMapper implements RowMapper<Book> {

@Override
public Book mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
    Book book = new Book();
    Author author = new Author();
    Publisher publisher = new Publisher();


    try {
        book.setBookId(rs.getInt("bookId"));
        book.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
        author = authorDAO.getAuthorById(rs.getInt("authId"));
        book.setAuthor(author);
        publisher = publisherDAO.getPublisherById(rs.getInt("pubId"));
        book.setPublisher(publisher);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return book;
}
```